# How to design a custom service website using Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, android, html, iphone, wordpress

Can the tool/programming language build this custom website. Feel free to tell me if it’s not possible to use Wordpress for this:

- The website should let users create an account
- The user should be able to create a listing, one or many
- User should be able to browse the listing created by other users and contact if needed.
- The user listing the item should be able to to set a price.
- The user browsing the listing can initiate a request for exchanging it with their listing, the listing user can accept or deny that users request.

Can you please tell me which tools/programming/DB would be needed to execute these features for a website, also what would be needed to execute the same for android/iPhone support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use `React` for web and `React Native` for IOS/Android, `MongoDB` for Database. Back-end can be accomplished by using either ExpressJs or NextJs. All these functions will be added using These `Tech`. WordPress will work for the only Website which runs on chrome/firefox. will not help you with Mobile App, you still can use it but not a good idea!

[To Learn React to building some cool stuff](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html), [All about React native](https://reactnative.dev/docs/tutorial), [MongoDB for Data Storing](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/index.htm), and [for Deployment Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So the front end and back end can be done by react ?

Comment: Oops I forgot to write it up! for the back-end, either NextJs or ExpressJs can be used!

Comment: Which would pair best with react, nextjs or expressjs?

Comment: @Zubair Both are best to React! if you want to learn just go for NextJs! NextJs can be used for a simple project like this! please consider marking my answer! To study NextJs https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/create-nextjs-app

Comment: @Zubair if you want the road map, let me know I'll share it with you!

Comment: Yes, a road map would certainly help

Comment: @Zubair https://hackernoon.com/the-2020-reactjs-developer-roadmap-8q143yan  2: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/the-2020-web-developer-roadmap-76503ddfb327 3: https://github.com/adam-golab/react-developer-roadmap/blob/master/roadmap.png?ref=hackernoon.com